# Customizing Rails flash notices, without bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, css, flash-message

i'm trying to find a way of customizing a number of rails flash[:notice]'s without the use of bootstrap. I know how to do it with bootstrap but I generally don't like using it and would rather style my app's myself..I kind of feel all of Bootstrap's default padding, media queries etc get in the way.

I've read that you can add_flash_types in your controller, but i'm a little stuck on how I would go about styling their color and implementing them.

Thanks in advance,
Justin

Answer (score 0):

`flash` is an array of hashes. You could add multiple hashes to the `flash`. Like `flash[:info], flash[:notice], flash[:alert] flash[:error]`. In view you could print all flash messages with some styling. Put you `css` along with message. Like

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg|
  <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}", class: 'my-class' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html.erb file you can display messages with a custom css class - `error-msg` in our case.

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
  <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: 'error-msg' %>
<% end -%>
```

In your application.css file (or other css file) you can style errors with your custom css.

```
.error-msg {
  color: red;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```